# Get data in user-defined type list from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, list, user-defined-types

I have a SQL Server four tables 'mapping' table `MappingACVP` as:

```
Author_ID | CoAuthor_ID | Venue_ID | Paper_ID | Year
----------------------------------------------------
677       | 42700       | 64309    | 812229   | 2005
677       | 42700       | 64309    | 812486   | 2005
677       | 42700       | 64309    | 818273   | 2005
677       | 42700       | 65182    | 812229   | 2005  
...       | ...         | ...      | ...      | ...  
...       | ...         | ...      | ...      | ...
```

By using Entity Framework, I got auto-generated code for all four tables included in Entity Framework Model i.e. `Authors.cs`, `CoAuthors_New.cs`, `Venues_New.cs` and `Papers_New.cs` as well, whereas tables other than `Authors` all have `Author_ID` as foreign key as a relationship.

The auto-generated code for class `Authors.cs` is as:

```
public partial class Authors
{
   public Authors()
   {
       this.CoAuthors_New = new HashSet<CoAuthors_New>();
       this.Papers_New = new HashSet<Papers_New>();
       this.Venues_New = new HashSet<Venues_New>();
   }

   public int id { get; set; }
   public int Author_ID { get; set; }
   public string Author_Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<CoAuthors_New> CoAuthors_New { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Papers_New> Papers_New { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Venues_New> Venues_New { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I want to declare a list as:

```
List<Authors> _eAthors = new List<Authors>();
```

and want to fetch values for filling this list from database (using `MappingACVP` table), whereas there is no `Year` property in `Authors.cs` class. So,

How will I fill `eAuthors` list from database?

Comment: @MLT can you get this ?

Comment: @Mat can you get this ?